# Should I create seperate referenced table or go with serialized data in a column?

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance

I have a table with name `app_client` with the below fields

> id, user_id, name, age, phone, gender, **related_entities_json (long text datatype)**,
>   created_at, updated_at

I have 200k+ records in this table and I found that the size is mainly increased (7 GB ) due to `related_entities_json` field.

So I want to know that should I move `related_entities_json` to a seperate table? And then access it's data when needed!

I don't want to open another question for this so i would also like to know that Will this increase performance during fetching/inserting data?

Entry in `related_entities_json` from a row

https://pastebin.com/y4XDCK4Y

Comment: *should I move related_entities_json to a seperate table?* Definitely. This is the most reasonable action. ENTITIES table and JOIN (clientID, entityID) table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  InnoDB does something like that for you.  If a table has any bulky `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns, those columns are stored "off-record".  This means that they go in a separate block(s) on disk.  Meanwhile, if you read only other columns, you are not 'wasting' time fetching the bulky columns.

Corollary:  Do not use `SELECT * ...`; instead specify the columns you really need.

(History:  Back when ENGINE=MyISAM was the typical table type, your idea was a good one.)

A tip:  Consider `COMPRESSing` and `UNCOMPRESSing` the JSON column in the client.  This may shrink your 7GB to 2-3GB, and speed up queries that do need to look at the JSON (because I/O costs more that CPU).

Comment: Thanks @Rick James I'm doing the same as you have suggested.